# EventHandler does not take params - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

I've built a fairly simple controller for my "MainWindow.fxml" file to deal with a button. I followed [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/connecting_scenebuilder_edited_fxml_to) tutorial. And I have correctly set the fx:id within the fxml doc. However on compilation I get the following error warning

> java: type java.beans.EventHandler does not take parameters

for the line

```
createVizButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
```

My full controller class looks like the following...

```
package sample;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.EventHandler;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class MainController implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    private Button createVizButton;
    @Override // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when initialization is complete
    public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {
        assert createVizButton != null : "fx:id=\"createButton\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainWindow.fxml'.";

        // initialize your logic here: all @FXML variables will have been injected
        createVizButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("That was easy, wasn't it?");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Your imports are incorrect:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.EventHandler;
```

should be

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
```